# Compiling error on microstrain_3dmgx2_imu package

Tags: ros, microstrain-3dmgx2-imu, imu-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using electric, with Ubuntu 11.10.

I've recently downloaded the stack imu_drivers (version 1.3.1) and I've done:

```
 $ rosdep install microstrain_3dmgx2_imu

 All required rosdeps installed successfully

 $ rosmake microstrain_3dmgx2_imu
```

and I get the followig error:

...

/home/andreu/rosSw-extra/imu_drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/imu_node.cc: In member function ‘void ImuNode::getData(sensor_msgs::Imu&)’:
/home/andreu/rosSw-extra/imu_drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/imu_node.cc:450:6: error: ‘Matrix3x3’ is not a member of ‘tf’
/home/andreu/rosSw-extra/imu_drivers/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/imu_node.cc:453:5: error: ‘Matrix3x3’ is not a member of ‘tf’

...

Has anyone compiled successfully this package under electric+Ubuntu11.10 ?

Thanks !

Andreu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12983/compiling-error-on-microstrain_3dmgx2_imu-package/) by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2012-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why not install the imu_drivers from debs? `sudo apt-get install ros-electric-imu-drivers`

I suspect that newer versions of the imu drivers use the Fuerte tf API; the last version of the imu drivers that was released into electric is 1.2.4

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on 2012-02-11**:
Great ! Thanks

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-11**:
Yes; you can infer the package name by replacing underscores in the package name with dashes, and prepending ros--. You can also search for deb packages with the package manager, such as 'apt-cache search imu-drivers' or 'apt-cache search ros-electric'

**Comment by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on 2012-02-11**:
THanks ! Installing the deb pkg works fine. But, from the ros stack name, how do you infer the deb package name ? Is there a common rule for ros that changes from "aa_bb" ros-stack name to "ros-electric-aa-bb" deb-pkg name ? THanks again !